# Hue works very slow

Tags: hadoop, hue, cloudera-cdh

I'm using CLoudera Hadoop 4.8 and I have a cluster with 4 nodes.
The problem is: if I start a Hive query with Hue it takes 5 hours to be completed.
The query is:

```
select count(*) from table_name
```

At this time the Nodes loadavg is

```
Node1 40 -- strongest node
Node2 20 
Node3 20
Node4 20
```

But if I start the same query from hive console it needs ~30 min to end. And loadavg is lower!

```
Node1 12 -- strongest node
Node2 6 
Node3 6
Node4 6
```

Why does it happens?

System:

```
OS: CentOS 6.5
Cloudera 4.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Hue version is it?

Hue submits the Hive query to either Beeswax Server or HiveServer2 which will run it (same as executing it from the shell). Do you see anything in the Beeswax or Hue logs (page /logs in Hue) that would indicate a kind of misconfiguration. You could also execute the query from the Hue node (where there is Beeswax or HiveServer2) to be sure that they are both using the same configuration.

Comment: Hue version is 2.5.0+217.
What should I find in logs?
There is no ERRORS. Only debug and info entries.